# Best technique to make latte art with an Aeroccino 3?

Tags: equipment, latte, nespresso, foamed-milk, latte-art

I want to know which are the best practices to make latte art with the Aeroccino 3.

- Which level of milk is optimal? Should I use the maximum for hot mark, maximum for cold mark or somewhere below or between the marks?
- Should I use the whisk with or without the spring?
- Do I need a metal milk jug?

My problem is that the milk turns out too foamy, and I believe it should be denser.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out https://youtu.be/X00xSAndJZU

I also find that the milk will be separated with the foam quite fast so you need to immediately pour the milk out of the can.
Shaking the can also help a lot as the milk will again emerge with foam and give silky result.